# Plotly Sankey chart cutting off when loops exists

Tags: python, plotly, sankey-diagram

I am trying to plot Sankey diagrams using [Plotly's Sankey](https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/) functionality. I can get Sankey diagrams to plot properly unless they contain loops (i.e. one state flows back into itself). When a loop occurs the chart sometimes gets cut off in the plot.

Example:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 0,
      thickness = 10,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = ["A", "B", "C"],
      color = "blue"
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = [0, 0, 0 ],
      target = [0, 1, 0 ],
      value = [8, 4, 2 ]
  ))])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Cut off loop example", font_size=10)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Notice how the circle is being cut off. I would like to have the plot show the complete circle, is there a way to do this? I have tried adding padding and increasing the size of the plot none of which has resolved the cut off issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve this by specifying the height and width directly in the layout specification. I set the values manually.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 0,
      thickness = 10,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = ["A", "B", "C"],
      color = "blue"
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = [0, 0, 0 ],
      target = [0, 1, 0 ],
      value = [8, 4, 2 ]
  ))])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Cut off loop example", font_size=10, width=1000, height=350)
fig.show()
```

[image]